# Infinispan GlobalConfigurationBuilder issue

Tags: java, java-8, keycloak, infinispan

The thing is that I have this fragment of code in my KeyCloak SPI where the configuration is initialized:

```
GlobalConfigurationBuilder global = GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder();
DefaultCacheManager cacheManager = new DefaultCacheManager(global.build());
ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.clustering().cacheMode(CacheMode.DIST_SYNC);
this.userAndCaptchaMap = cacheManager.administration().withFlags(CacheContainerAdmin.AdminFlag.VOLATILE).getOrCreateCache("myCache", builder.build());
```

While I'm trying to proceed this part of code the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport cannot be cast to org.infinispan.remoting.transport.Transport
    at org.infinispan.configuration.global.TransportConfigurationBuilder.defaultTransport(TransportConfigurationBuilder.java:216)
    at org.infinispan.configuration.global.GlobalConfigurationBuilder.defaultClusteredBuilder(GlobalConfigurationBuilder.java:295)
    at nexign.bsp.RecaptchaResetForm.create(RecaptchaResetForm.java:156)
    at nexign.bsp.RecaptchaResetForm.create(RecaptchaResetForm.java:26)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.createAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:72)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.isConditionalAuthenticator(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:334)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.fillListsOfExecutions(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:296)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow.processFlow(DefaultAuthenticationFlow.java:235)
    at org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor.authenticateOnly(AuthenticationProcessor.java:976)
```

Is it about a configuration or about versions of the Infinispan itself?

Comment: It looks like you may have different versions of Infinispan on the classpath. Can you verify please ?